# Postgres: Is it necessary to add an index for a "where is null" select query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

Given a table people e.g.:

```
id  name  emailed_at
1   Foo   2018-01-01
2   Bar   NULL
```

Is it necessary to add an index to `emailed_at` to have a performant `SELECT * FROM people WHERE emailed_at IS NULL` query?

UPDATE:
The actual table has around 12 columns, hundreds of thousands of rows, and only the most recent (~ 1 day old) records should have a NULL in that field.

Comment: An index is only as helpful as its selectivity. If most records have `null` value for `emailed_at`, the index is not going to help. If only a few `null`s are present, the index is going to speed things up.

Comment: How many rows does the table have? What percentage of them have a null email?

Comment: Updated with more info. Sounds like an index will help?

Comment: Create the index then check the execution plan and you will know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For two rows, there is no performance issue at all.  For a large table, an index is going to help.  `IS NULL` is the same as any other "equality" comparison.  It can take advantage of an index.

The benefit of indexing is when the table spans multiple (many?) data pages.  An index generally reduces the number of data pages that need to be processed.  If a lot of the `emailed_at` records are `NULL` (such as 50% in your example), then any given page is probably going to have `NULL` values -- and the index is much less useful.

Comment: Updated with more info. Sounds like an index will help?

Comment: @jemminger . . . Yes, an index should be helpful in the case you describe.